# Handle back navigation from bottom bar react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Hey I developed one application in react native functionality. Currently I am facing issue with go back to to previous screen. Example I took bottom tab bar and I place back button icon in first tab. now it have screen that contain number of functionality and navigate to different screen. now my problem is exam my screen contain 5 button A, B, C, D, E. When I click on button C it will navigate to next screen C1 and from C1 to C2. when I use android navigation back button panel it was navigate properly C2 to C1 and C1 to Home, But when I use bottom bar back button it was from C2 to directly home,  that is an issue. I have to maintain backstack functionality like when i click bottom bar back button it should navigate C2 to C1 and C1 to Home. provide some solution for it.

Thanks in advance. below is my app screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h47Hi.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
this.props.navigation.goBack()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 